# Django crispy-forms dynamic label_class and field_class

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I’m trying to create a form layout with a few fields that are of a different size than the other fields.  What is the best way to do this using crispy-forms?
For example, I’m laying out the form in rows where most of the rows have two fields but occasionally a single field will occupy the whole row.

```
--------------------------------------------------
| First Name            | Last Name              |
--------------------------------------------------
| User Name             | Email                  |
--------------------------------------------------
| Bio                                            |
--------------------------------------------------
```

In the example layout above, each field is composed of a label and the text input in the actual HTML (I just didn't know how to show this in the question).  I’m using Bootstrap 3 so on the first two lines I want the labels to have a class of ’col-sm-2’ and the input fields to have a class of ‘col-sm-4’ so that when rendered, they show up with two fields per row (i.e. 12 columns).  However, for the third row with the “Bio” field, I want the input field to be “col-sm-10’ to take up the whole row.

Here is some sample code that is close enough that someone may be able to help.

```
self.helper = FormHelper(self)
self.helper.form_tag = False
self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
self.helper.label_class = 'col-sm-2'
self.helper.field_class = 'col-sm-4'
self.helper.layout = Layout(
    MultiField(
        'Profile Information',
        Div('first_name', 'last_name'),
        Div(css_class='clearfix'),
        Div('username', 'email'),
        Div(css_class='clearfix'),
        Div('bio', css_class='col-sm-10'),
    ),
)
```

I’ve tried using several different combinations of Div, Field, and Row and using combinations css_class and wrapper_class as well as trying to create "custom" attributes but nothing works to give me the layout that I want.   I’ve even tried several different combinations of nested Div(Field) type structures but nothing worked.

There doesn’t seem to be a way to dynamically change the helper.field_class for just the “Bio” field row.  It seems really wrong to resort to using the HTML method but that’s all I can think to do for this as this point.

What is the right way to do this using crispy-forms?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar function (designed for bootstrap 2) that gets you part of the way there; it doesn't work with horizontal-forms like you requested, but you are able to generate dynamic rows:

```
from crispy_forms import helper
from crispy_forms import layout

def addBootstrapRow(helper, firstField, numFields, wrapperClasses):

        # set classes used for all fields if only one provided
        if type(wrapperClasses) in [str, unicode]:
            wrapperClasses = [wrapperClasses]*numFields

        # find first field, apply wrapper_class for each
        first = helper.layout.index(firstField)
        for i, cls in enumerate(wrapperClasses):
            helper[first+i].wrap(layout.Field, wrapper_class=cls)

        # put all these fields into a row
        helper[first:first+numFields].wrap_together(layout.Div, css_class="row-fluid")
```

To get a format similar (but not identical) to the one in your question, you can do this:

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = helper.FormHelper(self)
        addBootstrapRow(self.helper, 'first_name', 2, "span6")  # all fields same
        addBootstrapRow(self.helper, 'username', 2, ["span4", "span8"])  # fields diff.
        addBootstrapRow(self.helper, 'bio', 1, "span12")
```

Might not your exact solution, it may help others that stumble upon this question at least (like me).

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

From what I have found, there **isn't any simple solution to this problem**.

In 2014, a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms/issues/348) regarding setting the `label_class` individually for each field was created. However, this issue was **closed by the crispy forms developers as out-of-scope**.

In 2021, a [GitHub pull request](https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms/pull/1101) with changes allowing `label_class` and `field_class` on individual fields was created. However, this PR was **closed due to inactivity** of the PR author.

### Possible solutions

The answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24812267/crispy-forms-add-css-class-for-one-of-the-inputs) may help you with the problem. One possible solution could be to **create a custom field template** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32253371/11875147).