# crispy-forms: add css class for one of the inputs

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, django-crispy-forms

In my `forms.py` I have

```
[...]
self.helper.layout = Layout(
    Field('name'),
    Field('description'),
)
self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
self.helper.label_class = 'col-md-2 col-xs-3'
self.helper.field_class = 'col-md-10 col-xs-9'
[...]
```

which renders to

```
<div id="div_id_name" class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2 col-xs-3 requiredField" for="id_name">
        Name
    </label
    <div class="controls col-md-10 col-xs-9">
        <input id="id_name" class="textinput textInput form-control" type="text" name="name" maxlength="20">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="div_id_description" class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2 col-xs-3 requiredField" for="id_description">
        Description
    </label>
    <div class="controls col-md-10 col-xs-9">
        <textarea id="id_description" class="textarea form-control" rows="10" name="description" cols="40"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I would like *just* the name-input to be smaller, like this:

```
[...]
<div class="controls col-md-8 col-xs-7">
        <input id="id_name" class="textinput textInput form-control" type="text" name="name" maxlength="20">
    </div>
</div>
[...]
```

(How) can this be achieved in [crispy-forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see two possibilities:

#### 1. Use CSS

```
#div_id_name {
    font-weight: 0.8em;
}
```

#### 2. Override the field template

You can [override the field template](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/layouts.html#overriding-layout-objects-templates) of your field:

```
Field('field_name', template='my_field_template.html')
```

For a reference field template, see `site-packages/crispy_forms/templates/bootstrap3/field.html`.

#### (3. Waiting)

There's an open issue on Github for this: https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms/issues/348

Answer (score 6):

To you helper layout:

```
self.helper.layout = Layout(
    Field('name'),
    Field('description'),
```

add `css_class`:

```
Field('field_name', css_class="controls col-md-8 col-xs-7")
```

Here is the docs [link](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/layouts.html?highlight=fieldset#layout-objects-attributes)

Comment: Thanks, but as far as I can see this only changes the `inputs` css-classes, not the css-classes of the wrapper-div. However, the wrapper-div is decissive in this case.

Comment: In the same crispy-forms layout link that i pasted, there is a Div() function, and also HTML, so maybe those can work.  I use both for my crispy form for custom css on select fields.

Comment: thanks, but I think `HTML()` cannot really help (or can it) and `Div()` would cover both, the label and the input inside, however I need to change the div that wraps *just* the input (not the outer div that also wraps the label)

Answer (score 5):

The only way to get this working is not using some form.helpers.

My config is

```
    # from
    self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
    self.helper.label_class = "col-md-2"
    self.helper.field_class = "col-md-10"
    # -> to
    self.helper.form_class = 'form-vertical'
    #self.helper.label_class = "col-md-2"
    #self.helper.field_class = "col-md-10"
    Fieldset('Address',
                 Div(
                     #I need to set size for every field wrapped in a div
                     Div('tipo_logradouro', css_class="col-md-6"), 
                     Div('logradouro', css_class='col-md-6'),
                     css_class='row'
                 ),
     )
```

I know this old but I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

One way to add a custom css class to a crispy-forms *Field* would be to wrap it in a *Div* with a custom *css_class* attribute:

```
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Div, Field

self.helper.layout = Layout(
    Div(
        Field('name'), css_class="my_fancy_class_name"
    ),
    Field('description'),
)
```

For example, now you can customize your Field with some css:

```
.my_fancy_class_name {
    font-size: 200%;  /* You can change the font size */
    color: green;    /* You can change the font color */
    display: none;  /* You can even hide the Field */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it like this:

```
Field('name', wrapper_class="col-md-6"),
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and looking in the field.html template, I found that there's a thing called wrapper_class that you can use in this way:

```
Field('name', wrapper_class="col-md-8 col-xs-7")
```

You can find the documentation in this link https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layouts.html under the Field layout element.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you wrap those fields in a div? Doesnt this solve your problem?

```
self.helper.layout = Layout(
    Div(Field('name',maxlength=20),css_class = 'controls col-md-8 col-xs-7'),
    Field('description'),
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but this is more than 2 years ago. I simply don't know... :(