# align field on django-crispy forms horizontally to centre of page?

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I have a one field form which I want to align horizontally and centre of page.

I want to have autofocus and placeholder enabled.

Here is my code:

```
class VinForm(forms.Form):
    VIN = forms.CharField(max_length=17, label='VIN')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(VinForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        #self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-5'
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        #self.helper.form_class = 'form-inline col-md-12'
        #self.helper.label_class = 'col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3'
        #self.helper.field_class = 'col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12'
        #self.helper.form_class = 'form-inline'

        self. helper.layout = Layout(
            FieldWithButtons('VIN', StrictButton("Go!"), autofocus=True, placeholder='JN1HJ01F8RT231164'),
        #     Div(
        # Div('VIN',css_class='col-md-6',autofocus=True, placeholder='JN1HJ01F8RT231164'),
        # css_class='row',
        #     ),
        #     Fieldset(
        #         #'Get Driving profile',
        #    Field('VIN', autofocus=True, placeholder='JN1HJ01F8RT231164'),
         #    ),
        #     FormActions(
        #         Submit('submit', 'get vehicle info'),
        #    ),
        # )
        )
```

you can see from my code above that I tried many things still none worked. Here is how it looks.

[image]

It lacks

1) center of page

2) inline form

3) autofocus and placeholders are not working

I am using twitter bootstrap3

Answer (score 1):

I do the below. Note 'Field' in the snippet below, where we specify additional css in css_class. Here is the docs [link](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layouts.html?highlight=fieldset#layout-objects-attributes)

```
 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(

            Row(
                HTML('<h3>About you</h4>'),
                Column(Field('computers', css_class='text-center'), css_class='col-md-12 text-center')
            ),
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24812832/960471

Answer (score -3):

The crispy forms documentation shows how to do horizontal forms for bootstrap, perhaps that will help.  http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/crispy_tag_forms.html?highlight=horizontal#bootstrap3-horizontal-forms